# Performing PCA on numeric values in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, pca

I am performing PCA on the numeric columns present in my dataset.These numeric columns are in the same range so still do i need to standardize( Using PROC STANDARD)  those columns before performing PCA on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to standardize them before running `proc princomp`. Add the `std` option to produce standardized  principal component scores.

```
proc princomp data=mydata out=scores std;
    var var1 var2 var3;
run;
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. But just a small doubt i have, if var1,var2 and var3 are in the same range. still we need to add this standardized option in the princomp procedure.

Comment: If they have the exact same range then no, you would not need to standardize your output before subsequent steps. Nonetheless, it is highly recommended before doing additional modeling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Cleared my doubt